# Writing script so it will save command output and save it as different text with date stamp

Tags: bash, centos7

This is my first scripting attempt and what I need to do is monitor partitions on my CentOS 7 server. So what I want to do is execute the `df -h` command and save the output to the file every hour.

I have read up on the cron jobs etc. and don't have a problem with that. The problem I am facing is the physical script I have to write.

I want the command to run `df -h` and save the output with a date stamp if possible to a NEW txt file or just to add to the same file as long as the date stamp is there I can go and review it later. I have created a `.sh` file and in there i have

```
#!/bin/sh
df -h | more filename.txt
```

At the moment all am getting is the following - I have tried adding date commands but no joy.

[image: script output]

Comment: Can you edit your question and include how you've tried to add the date command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example shows different ways how you could use the command `date` within a function() to echo the date into a file together with another command output, as well how you could create new filenames with timestamp.

```
#!/bin/bash

timestamp() {
  echo -n $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T")
}

echo -e "$(timestamp)\n$(df -h)" > diskusage.$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%m").log
```

Comment: Thanks you are a genius.

Comment: Sorry man, I noticed now it executes the commands but it overwrites the files in the directory... Anyway it can just add the logs instead of overwriting. The timestamp and everything is perfect. It overwrites the contents in the log but doesnt replace the log name etc. it still says the old date with new info in it. I need a new log file with that info in if you can help me out please. I have no coding experience so to me nothing makes sense in there..

Answer (score 0):

```
$> cat $HOME/bin/timestamp
#!/bin/bash
date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S
```

and furthermore:

```
$> cat $HOME/bin/df-script.sh
#!/bin/bash
df -h >| $HOME/filename-$($HOME/bin/timestamp)
```

Comment: Is the commands just to add the date? If you can put some explanation to it if you do not mind. So the date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S command works on its own but how will i incorporate it with the entire command line i have df -h |more filename.txt and also how can i let it add contents to the file instead of replacing it? When i execute the command more than once and look at the contents in the file it will show me one output? Or must i create a separate txt file each time i run the command which i do not mind but how do i do it exactly?

Comment: Create a `timestamp` script with the contents I gave, then do `chmod 755 $HOME/bin/timestamp`. This assumes you have $HOME/bin in your PATH. You can also create a df-script.sh script like I listed, and just call that: from the cli, or just call `df -h >| $HOME/filename-"$($HOME/bin/timestamp)"` from the cli.